# On some special 5-tuples in projective space $PG(3,2)$

Tags: combinatorics, projective-space, finite-geometry

Projective space $PG(3,2)$ has nice 5-tuples of points like $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, $(0,0,0,1)$, $(1,1,1,1).$ This 5-tuple is "nice" because these points with their pairwise sums cover whole space $PG(3,2)$.

What is the name for such 5-tuples? In what combinatorial problems do they arise?

Answer (score 2):

This set of points is an example of a *frame*. More precisely, a frame is a set of $n+2$ points in a $n$-dimensional projective space such that no hyperplane contains $n+1$ of them.

Frames are nice in general because we can describe a matrix for a linear transformation by considering where it sends the points in a frame (whereas in most situations a set of points forming a basis won't allow this).

The property of the pairwise sums giving the whole space is, I think, not an especially interesting property, and I don't think there is a nice generalization over fields with order greater than 2.

Answer (score 1):

This works for any basis of $V(4,2)$. Let $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, and $v_4$ be any such basis, and let $v_5=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4$. Then the other ten points are the spans of the vectors: $v_1+v_2$, $v_1+v_3$, $v_1+v_4$, $v_2+v_3$, $v_2+v_4$ and $v_3+v_4$, as well as $v_1+v_5 = v_2+v_3+v_4$, $v_2+v_5$, $v_3+v_5$ and $v_4+v_5$.

Comment: Do they have any combinatorial meaning?

Comment: Not really, to the best of my knowledge. They form a cap (no three collinear), but there are larger caps. It's possible this is just an artifact of how small PG(3,2) is, but it might be interesting to try to generalize to higher dimensions, to see if such sets exists. Good luck!